# How do I Resize the scroll view so that all of the edges are flush with the container view’s edges?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistoryboard

In the [AutoLayout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html), it explains to "After the container view is created, create a scroll view and place it inside of the container view. Resize the scroll view so that all of the edges are flush with the container view’s edges, by setting the distance to 0."

How do I make all edges "flush with the container's view" in storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add the Scroll View In your View Controller
- Resize it to fill all your view controller
- now select it and click the second menu option from bottom-right buttons in storyboard
- you'll see four constraints on the top of that menu. click on all four of them to enable the constraints (constraints will turn into red lines) and enter values 0 for all four of them.
- add the constraints by clicking the bottom button from the menu.